# Имя экземпляра сервера Microsoft sql Server

Tags: sql-server

Я установил на компьютер *Sql Managment Studio 2012* и при ее запуске требуется ввести имя экземпляра сервера.

К сожалению, не имею даже представления, какое имя требуется.

Где можно посмотреть, какие экземпляра уже существуют на компьютере? К примеру, кто-то сделал именнованный экземпляр и я об не знал.

А самое главное: где посмотреть имена экземпляров, которые можно использовать при входе через *managment studio*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В дополнение к ответу @Vesper - кроме обычных экземпляров SQL Server, которые запущены как отдельные сервисы, есть еще LocalDB.

Это локальные экземпляры SQL Server Express, которые существуют только для текущего пользователя. И которые предназначены прежде всего для разработки приложений, а не для их постоянного хостинга.

Их список можно посмотреть командой

```
SqlLocalDB.exe i
```

утилита обычно есть в path. Если нет, то полный путь к ней выглядит как:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe i
```

Comment: Вы сам сервер поставили, или только Management Studio?

Comment: @msi вы у меня спрашиваете?

Comment: @msi, Я поставил visual studio 2013 и managment studio 2012, так же я знал, что вместе с VS 2013 ставится сервер и хотел понять как мне на нем поработать. Вместе с managment studio 2012 я поставил localdb. И уже когда заходил в MS2012 я использовал для входа имя сервера "(localdb)\v11.0". Но вот откуда взялось именное такое имя а не другое меня и интересовало.

Comment: @PashaPash, извиняюсь, не ту ссылку нажал.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, имя будет `MSSQLSERVER` или default (без имени). Посмотреть можно в службах ПК, службы Microsoft SQL Server имеют префикс `MSSQL$`. Если интересует программно, можно выполнить нечто вроде (Powershell):

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_Service -Filter "name like 'MSSQL$%'" | % {$_.name.substring(6) }
```

Comment: Я зашел в Sql Server Configuration Manager, далее открыл вкладку службы sql server, но там ничего нет, просто пустой список. Команда для powershell так же ничего не вывела, хотя в managment studio я могу использовать имя сервера "(localdb)\v11.0"